# Combine plots with same y-axes different x-axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking into how the bond market reacts to certain events in a seven day window.

Therefore, I want to create a figure that plots the bond yield reactions around the dates. My data looks like following

```
df <- Date       APP  DE10 
      2014-09-22 0    1.010 
      2014-09-19 0    1.043
      2014-09-18 0    1.081
      2014-09-17 0    1.050
      2014-09-16 0    1.061
      2014-09-15 0    1.067
      2014-09-12 1    1.082
      2014-09-11 0    1.041
      2014-09-10 0    1.047
      2014-09-09 0    0.996
      2014-09-08 0    0.953
      2014-09-05 0    0.928
      2014-09-04 1    0.970
      2014-09-03 0    0.955
      2014-09-02 0    0.931
      2014-09-01 0    0.882
```

APP is a dummy that indicates the date of events. 
I made the figure below using grid.arrange to put together each country's bond yields plotted as

```
DE10 <- ggplot(Bond10) + 
   geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=DE10)) +
   labs(title="Germany", x="", y="Bond yield") +
   scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c('2017-10-23','2017-10-30')), 
   expand=c(0.1,0))+
   geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date("2017-10-26"), color="Event"))+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.3, 0.6), expand = c(0.1,0)) +  
   theme(legend.position='none',
       axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
       plot.margin=unit(c(0.2,0.2,0,0.2), "cm"))
```

I want the figure below to include multiple lines in each plot under each country plot to see how strong the reactions have been to different events.

[Figure of bond yields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2OQQ.png)

[image]

Comment: How did you go from `df` to `Bond10` data frame?

Comment: Redefine the x axis to be days before/after a certain date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to what @MichaelChirico suggested, here a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) solution

```
require(tidyverse)
Bond10$Date <- ymd(Bond10$Date) #needed to do this because the dates were imported as characters 

Bond10 <- Bond10 %>% mutate(APP_date = ifelse(APP == 1, Date, NA))

ggplot(Bond10) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=DE10)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept= APP_date , color="Event"))

#I removed the redundant bits and pieces, especially your totally wrong x-limits
```

[image]